# Do the calories from high-GI foods eaten in the morning count towards the energy you have in your evening workout?

Tags: bodybuilding, calories, carbohydrate

I guess I have multiple questions stemming from this one question actually.

Example scenario:
Let's say a bodybuilder needs 2500 calories to be in a caloric surplus. Of his daily calorie intake, 15% comes from simple sugars and most are taken every morning. He worksout at 6pm 3-4 days a week.

1. Do the calories from the morning sugars count toward his calorie surplus even though they were not timed closer to the workout?
2. Similarly, since his simpler carbs were taken so many hours before the 6pm workout, is there a good chance those would have had enough time for some of them to go towards fat storage rather than waiting around in the bloodstream for his 6pm workout (because they're not complex carbs)?

Comment: Glucose will be stored in the liver and muscles, so this shouldn't be a problem. You only need to be careful when you haven't eaten well a few days in a row, e.g., after recovering from illness. Especially if you are physically very fit, it can happen that you will feel very strong when your energy levels are actually too low and you can then faint during exercise. But under normal circumstances this won't happen.

Comment: Your answers in order (including title) are yes yes no.

Comment: @CountIblis, you may want to add that as an answer